# return a value from checkbox_CheckChanged

Tags: c#, winforms, events

How can I get a value returned from the checkbox_CheckChanged event please? Its a winforms app, and both the form and the checkbox are created programmatically. Thanks for all and any help.

Comment: Where's your code. Can you provide that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Controls event handlers are always "void" and you cant change the [return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325396/why-do-event-handlers-always-have-a-return-type-of-void). Instead you can take an external variable and you change that value only in when the CheckedChanged Event occurs.

```
public bool checkedthecheckbox { get; set; }

CheckBox testchbox = new CheckBox();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    testchbox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(testchbox_CheckedChanged);
}

void testchbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (testchbox.Checked)
        checkedthecheckbox = true;
    else
        checkedthecheckbox = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all who answered, and specially to skk for the particular answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the value from 'sender' object.

```
CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) sender;
bool result = chk.Checked;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the state of the Checkbox by casting the sender object from the event arguments:

```
public void Method1()
{
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
    checkBox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(checkBox_CheckedChanged);
}

void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox c = (CheckBox)sender;
    bool resutlt = c.Checked;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CheckState.Checked` or `CheckState.Unchecked`, which is built in C#. Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lsbx_layers.Items.Count; i++) {
    if (lsbx_layers.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked) {
        //set  boolean variable to true
    } else if (lsbx_layers.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Unchecked) {
         //set  boolean variable to false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got an alternative to change the regular check box changed event into an event that provides you with the changed `Checked` value directly.

You could, for example, use it this way:

```
var myForm = new MyForm();
myForm.CheckBoxChanged += v =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("The value of the checkbox changed to {0}", v);
};
```

Here's the class definition:

```
public class MyForm
{
    public event Action<bool> CheckBoxChanged;
    private CheckBox testchbox = new CheckBox();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testchbox.CheckedChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            var cbc = this.CheckBoxChanged;
            if (cbc != null)
            {
                cbc(testchbox.Checked);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.