# How to 'await' raising an EventHandler event

Tags: c#, events, mvvm, .net-4.5, async-await

Sometimes the event pattern is used to raise events in MVVM applications by or a child viewmodel to send a message to its parent viewmodel in a loosely coupled way like this.

**Parent ViewModel**

```
searchWidgetViewModel.SearchRequest += (s,e) => 
{
    SearchOrders(searchWidgitViewModel.SearchCriteria);
};
```

**SearchWidget ViewModel**

```
public event EventHandler SearchRequest;

SearchCommand = new RelayCommand(() => {

    IsSearching = true;
    if (SearchRequest != null) 
    {
        SearchRequest(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    IsSearching = false;
});
```

---

In refactoring my application for .NET4.5 I am making as much as code possible to use `async` and `await`. However the following doesn't work (well I really wasn't expecting it to)

```
 await SearchRequest(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

The framework definitely does this to call event handlers [such as this](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/c/1514-async-await-and-the-ui-problem.html), but I'm not sure how it does it?

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   textBlock1.Text = "Click Started";
   await DoWork();
   textBlock2.Text = "Click Finished";
}
```

Anything I've found on the subject of raising events asynchrously [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7a34yad.aspx) [ancient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx) but I can't find something in the framework to support this.

How can I `await` the calling of an event but remain on the UI thread.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: it doesn't compile. you can't await something that returns void which this does

Comment: Do you really need to wait until all the handlers complete? Can't you just start them and let their `async` parts complete without waiting for them?

Comment: Microsoft now provides an `AsyncEventHandler` in [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading/) package

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Events don't mesh perfectly with `async` and `await`, as you've discovered.

The way UIs handle `async` events is different than what you're trying to do. The UI [provides a `SynchronizationContext` to its `async` events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx), enabling them to resume on the UI thread. It does *not* ever "await" them.

**Best Solution (IMO)**

I think the best option is to build your own `async`-friendly pub/sub system, using [`AsyncCountdownEvent`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-3-asynccountdownevent/) to know when all handlers have completed.

**Lesser Solution #1**

`async void` methods do notify their `SynchronizationContext` when they start and finish (by incrementing/decrementing the count of asynchronous operations). All UI `SynchronizationContext`s ignore these notifications, but you *could* build a wrapper that tracks it and returns when the count is zero.

Here's an example, using `AsyncContext` from my [AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx):

```
SearchCommand = new RelayCommand(() => {
  IsSearching = true;
  if (SearchRequest != null) 
  {
    AsyncContext.Run(() => SearchRequest(this, EventArgs.Empty));
  }
  IsSearching = false;
});
```

However, in this example the UI thread is *not* pumping messages while it's in `Run`.

**Lesser Solution #2**

You could also make your own `SynchronizationContext` based on a nested `Dispatcher` frame that pops itself when the count of asynchronous operations reaches zero. However, you then introduce re-entrancy problems; `DoEvents` was left out of WPF on purpose.

Comment: the link to your AsyncEx library is now broken

Answer (score 54):

**Edit:** This doesn't work well for multiple subscribers, so unless you only have one I wouldn't recommend using this.

---

Feels slightly hacky - but I have never found anything better:

Declare a delegate. This is identical to [`EventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler) but returns a task instead of void

```
public delegate Task AsyncEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

You can then run the following and as long as the handler declared in the parent uses `async` and `await` properly then this will run asynchronously:

```
if (SearchRequest != null) 
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Starting...");
    await SearchRequest(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    Debug.WriteLine("Completed");
}
```

Sample handler:

```
 // declare handler for search request
 myViewModel.SearchRequest += async (s, e) =>
 {                    
     await SearchOrders();
 };
```

Note: I've never tested this with multiple subscribers and not sure how this will work - so if you need multiple subscribers then make sure to test it carefully.

Comment: Pretty good idea, but unfortunately the `await` is completed when any handler completes. That is, it does not wait for all tasks to complete.

Comment: This is what I've been using for the last two years :-) maybe I just got away with it but I will have to check this out-appreciate you commenting.

Comment: Yeah, it would be great if you can figure out a way to make it await all tasks. It would save us the need to implement pub/sub. I tried but can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: @Laith - I've double checked and it does seem to be working for me (I put debug WriteLine commands before and after the await call and the completed message didn't appear until after the search completed). did you use `async` on your event handler (added to answer) - and are you using multiple subscribers (untested)

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about multiple subscribers. If you use `+=` multiple times, the first `Task` to finish ends the `await` statement. The other tasks still continue, but are not awaited.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/3325424/429091](this answer about events returning values) suggests that the `await` would see the `Task` returned by the last handler to execute. Discussed in that answer’s comments, you may use [`Delegate.GetInvocationList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to manually execute the handlers individually and wrap their return in a `Task.WhenAll()`.

Comment: I tried doing the same with `public delegate Task MyEventHandlerAsync` and `public event MyEventHandlerAsync` and got this error `System.ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.`

Comment: Works well for single subscriber. Thanks!

Comment: I sort of hate how this is still getting upvotes lol ;-)

Answer (score 40):

Based on Simon_Weaver's answer, I created a helper class that can handle multiple subscribers, and has a similar syntax to c# events.

```
public class AsyncEvent<TEventArgs> where TEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private readonly List<Func<object, TEventArgs, Task>> invocationList;
    private readonly object locker;

    private AsyncEvent()
    {
        invocationList = new List<Func<object, TEventArgs, Task>>();
        locker = new object();
    }

    public static AsyncEvent<TEventArgs> operator +(
        AsyncEvent<TEventArgs> e, Func<object, TEventArgs, Task> callback)
    {
        if (callback == null) throw new NullReferenceException("callback is null");

        //Note: Thread safety issue- if two threads register to the same event (on the first time, i.e when it is null)
        //they could get a different instance, so whoever was first will be overridden.
        //A solution for that would be to switch to a public constructor and use it, but then we'll 'lose' the similar syntax to c# events             
        if (e == null) e = new AsyncEvent<TEventArgs>();

        lock (e.locker)
        {
            e.invocationList.Add(callback);
        }
        return e;
    }

    public static AsyncEvent<TEventArgs> operator -(
        AsyncEvent<TEventArgs> e, Func<object, TEventArgs, Task> callback)
    {
        if (callback == null) throw new NullReferenceException("callback is null");
        if (e == null) return null;

        lock (e.locker)
        {
            e.invocationList.Remove(callback);
        }
        return e;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(object sender, TEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        List<Func<object, TEventArgs, Task>> tmpInvocationList;
        lock (locker)
        {
            tmpInvocationList = new List<Func<object, TEventArgs, Task>>(invocationList);
        }

        foreach (var callback in tmpInvocationList)
        {
            //Assuming we want a serial invocation, for a parallel invocation we can use Task.WhenAll instead
            await callback(sender, eventArgs);
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, you declare it in your class, for example:

```
public AsyncEvent<EventArgs> SearchRequest;
```

To subscribe an event handler, you'll use the familiar syntax (the same as in Simon_Weaver's answer):

```
myViewModel.SearchRequest += async (s, e) =>
{                    
   await SearchOrders();
};
```

To invoke the event, use the same pattern we use for c# events (only with InvokeAsync):

```
var eventTmp = SearchRequest;
if (eventTmp != null)
{
   await eventTmp.InvokeAsync(sender, eventArgs);
}
```

If using c# 6, one should be able to use the null conditional operator and write this instead:

```
await (SearchRequest?.InvokeAsync(sender, eventArgs) ?? Task.CompletedTask);
```

Comment: Very intelligent

Comment: await SearchRequest?.InvokeAsync(...) -- unfortunately, this doesn't work. We can't await null.

Comment: You're right, when I wrote this c# 6 was not released yet and I didn't know exactly how the semantics would work: you should be able to write `await (SearchRequest?.InvokeAsync(..) ?? Task.CompletedTask)` though, not sure if it's actually more convenient.

Comment: Very good solution, i'd opt for enforcing the usage of a public constructor though in case the thread safety issue becomes a problem

Comment: Can it be "public AsyncEvent<EventArgs> SearchRequest { get; }" as I would like it to be a part of an interface and fields are not supported there (properties are). It does not work without the setter, though.

Comment: @ed22 the "+" operator is considered a setter so you'll need a public setter on the property and then it will work, see example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NdWeLq. If you don't want a public setter you can replace the "+" and "-" operators with normal methods (i.e Subscribe and Unsubscribe).

Answer (score 12):

To answer the direct question: I do not think `EventHandler` allows implementations to communicate sufficiently back to the invoker to allow proper awaiting. You might be able to perform tricks with a custom synchronization context, but if you care about waiting for the handlers, it is better that the handlers are able to return their `Task`s back to the invoker. By making this part of the delegate’s signature, it is clearer that the delegate will be `await`ed.

I suggest using the [`Delgate.GetInvocationList()` approach described in Ariel’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34493958/429091) mixed with ideas from [tzachs’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30739162/429091). Define your own `AsyncEventHandler<TEventArgs>` delegate which returns a `Task`. Then use an extension method to hide the complexity of invoking it correctly. I think this pattern makes sense if you want to execute a bunch of asynchronous event handlers and wait for their results.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public delegate Task AsyncEventHandler<TEventArgs>(
    object sender,
    TEventArgs e)
    where TEventArgs : EventArgs;

public static class AsyncEventHandlerExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<AsyncEventHandler<TEventArgs>> GetHandlers<TEventArgs>(
        this AsyncEventHandler<TEventArgs> handler)
        where TEventArgs : EventArgs
        => handler.GetInvocationList().Cast<AsyncEventHandler<TEventArgs>>();

    public static Task InvokeAllAsync<TEventArgs>(
        this AsyncEventHandler<TEventArgs> handler,
        object sender,
        TEventArgs e)
        where TEventArgs : EventArgs
        => Task.WhenAll(
            handler.GetHandlers()
            .Select(handleAsync => handleAsync(sender, e)));
}
```

This allows you to create a normal .net-style `event`. Just subscribe to it as you normally would.

```
public event AsyncEventHandler<EventArgs> SomethingHappened;

public void SubscribeToMyOwnEventsForNoReason()
{
    SomethingHappened += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        SomethingSynchronous();
        // Safe to touch e here.
        await SomethingAsynchronousAsync();
        // No longer safe to touch e here (please understand
        // SynchronizationContext well before trying fancy things).
        SomeContinuation();
    };
}
```

Then simply remember to use the extension methods to invoke the event rather than invoking them directly. If you want more control in your invocation, you may use the `GetHandlers()` extension. For the more common case of waiting for all the handlers to complete, just use the convenience wrapper `InvokeAllAsync()`. In many patterns, events either don’t produce anything the caller is interested in or they communicate back to the caller by modifying the passed in `EventArgs`. (Note, if you can assume a synchronization context with dispatcher-style serialization, your event handlers may mutate the `EventArgs` safely within their synchronous blocks because the continuations will be marshaled onto the dispatcher thread. This will magically happen for you if, for example, you invoke and `await` the event from a UI thread in winforms or WPF. Otherwise, you may have to use locking when mutating `EventArgs` in case if any of your mutations happen in a continuation which gets run on the threadpool).

```
public async Task Run(string[] args)
{
    if (SomethingHappened != null)
        await SomethingHappened.InvokeAllAsync(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

This gets you closer to something that looks like a normal event invocation, except that you have to use `.InvokeAllAsync()`. And, of course, you still have the normal issues that come with events such as needing to guard invocations for events with no subscribers to avoid a `NullArgumentException`.

Note that I am **not** using `await SomethingHappened?.InvokeAllAsync(this, EventArgs.Empty)` because `await` explodes on `null`. You could use the following call pattern if you want, but it can be argued that the parens are ugly and the `if` style is generally better for various reasons:

```
await (SomethingHappened?.InvokeAllAsync(this, EventArgs.Empty) ?? Task.CompletedTask);
```

Comment: Easy to implement, easy to use. Amazing!

Comment: thank you so much for this elegant solution. i'm using it [here](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities/blob/cd2b948a436f5cf12ffd479c9d469cf99f757a6c/MongoDB.Entities/Core/Watcher.cs#L13) in my mongodb library if anyone wants to see an example.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `AsyncEventHandler` delegate from the [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading/) package provided by Microsoft and is used in Visual Studio from what I understand.

```
private AsyncEventHandler _asyncEventHandler;
```

```
_asyncEventHandler += DoStuffAsync;

Debug.WriteLine("Async invoke incoming!");
await _asyncEventHandler.InvokeAsync(this, EventArgs.Empty);
Debug.WriteLine("Done.");
```

```
private async Task DoStuffAsync(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Debug.WriteLine("hello from async event handler");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Output:
**Async invoke incoming!

hello from async event handler

Done.**

Comment: This is by far the best solution!

Answer (score 5):

I know it is an old question, but my best solution was in using **TaskCompletionSource**.

See the code:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
service.loginCreateCompleted += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
};
await tcs.Task;
```

Comment: This is good if you only need to await the first callback of an event. It would probably be a good idea to remove the event handler after the await.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using custom event handlers, you might want to take a look at the [DeferredEvents](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DeferredEvents/), as it will allow you to raise and await for the handlers of an event, like this:

```
await MyEvent.InvokeAsync(sender, DeferredEventArgs.Empty);
```

The event handler will do something like this:

```
public async void OnMyEvent(object sender, DeferredEventArgs e)
{
    var deferral = e.GetDeferral();

    await DoSomethingAsync();

    deferral.Complete();
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `using` pattern like this:

```
public async void OnMyEvent(object sender, DeferredEventArgs e)
{
    using (e.GetDeferral())
    {
        await DoSomethingAsync();
    }
}
```

You can read about the DeferredEvents [here](https://www.pedrolamas.com/2017/04/04/await-your-event-handlers-completion-with-deferred-events/).

Comment: Interesting approach, takes a different angle than some other solutions. I still personally prefer to have the handler return `Task` and extract it by calling `GetInvocationList()`. For your usage example in this SO answer, I think it would be better to use the `using (e.GetDeferral()) {}` pattern variation because it’s less fragile.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear on what you mean by "How can I `await` the calling of an event but remain on the UI thread".  Do you want the event handler to be executed on the UI thread?  If that's the case then you can do something like this:

```
var h = SomeEvent;
if (h != null)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => h(this, EventArgs.Empty),
        Task.Factory.CancellationToken,
        Task.Factory.CreationOptions,
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Which wraps the invocation of the handler in a `Task` object so that you can use `await`, since you can't use `await` with a `void` method--which is where your compile error stems from.

But, I'm not sure what benefit you expect to get out of that.

I think there's a fundamental design issue there.  It's fine to kick of some background work on a click event and you can implement something that supports `await`.  But, what's the effect on how the UI can be used?  e.g. if you have a `Click` handler that kicks off an operation that takes 2 seconds, do you want the user to be able to click that button while the operation is pending?  Cancellation and timeout are additional complexities.  I think much more understanding of the usability aspects needs to be done here.

Comment: in the example above I put 'IsSearching=true' and 'IsSearching=false' around the call. These are MVVM properties that would need to execute on the UI thread, prehaps to gray out the 'Search' button. Ultimately my question is that WPF (the Dispatcher?) can call a void event handler asynchronously like the 'button1_Click' event above and I want to know how they do that

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Well, you can't `await` a method that returns `void`, you can only `await` a method that returns `Task<T>` or `Task`.  So, if you want to invoke an event handler asynchronously, you have to wrap it in a `Task` object, which I showed in my answer.

Comment: so do you think this is what WPF does when it calls my event handlers that are declared to be async?

Comment: The `async` modifier just tells the compiler to generate an async state machine to manage any `await` keywords it encounters *within* the method (more to manage the lines after the `await`s).  It doesn't do anything as far as externally viewing the method.  i.e., it doesn't make the method usable by `await`.  `await` only depends on the method returning a `Task` variant.  So, WPF  is probably just calling your method synchronously.  To call it asynchronously with `await` it would have to do what I detailed in my answer: wrap it in a `Task` object.

Comment: You can certainly write an event handler that returns `Task`, but nothing else is going to call it asynchronously, directly.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver I know its some time ago, but actually the await is compiled to `Task.GetAwaiter().OnComplete(()=> /* your follow up code */)` 
Async Methods will complete synchronously if no Method is awaited. If your UI Calls async Methods, only the await-Part will be executed on a seperate Thread, so you won't need to litter your code with `Dispatcher.Invoke()` stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Since delegates (and events are delegates) implement the Asynchronous Programming Model (APM), you could use the [TaskFactory.FromAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync(v=vs.110).aspx) method.  (See also [Tasks and the Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0).)

```
public event EventHandler SearchRequest;

public async Task SearchCommandAsync()
{
    IsSearching = true;
    if (SearchRequest != null)
    {
        await Task.Factory.FromAsync(SearchRequest.BeginInvoke, SearchRequest.EndInvoke, this, EventArgs.Empty, null);
    }
    IsSearching = false;
}
```

The above code, however, will invoke the event on a thread pool thread, i.e. it will not capture the current synchronization context.  If this is a problem, you could modify it as follows:

```
public event EventHandler SearchRequest;

private delegate void OnSearchRequestDelegate(SynchronizationContext context);

private void OnSearchRequest(SynchronizationContext context)
{
    context.Send(state => SearchRequest(this, EventArgs.Empty), null);
}

public async Task SearchCommandAsync()
{
    IsSearching = true;
    if (SearchRequest != null)
    {
        var search = new OnSearchRequestDelegate(OnSearchRequest);
        await Task.Factory.FromAsync(search.BeginInvoke, search.EndInvoke, SynchronizationContext.Current, null);
    }
    IsSearching = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To continue on [Simon Weaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16940/simon-weaver)'s answer, I tried the following

```cs
        if (SearchRequest != null)
        {
            foreach (AsyncEventHandler onSearchRequest in SearchRequest.GetInvocationList())
            {
                await onSearchRequest(null, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
```

This seams to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class FileProcessEventHandlerExtensions
{
    public static Task InvokeAsync(this FileProcessEventHandler handler, object sender, FileProcessStatusEventArgs args)
     => Task.WhenAll(handler.GetInvocationList()
                            .Cast<FileProcessEventHandler>()
                            .Select(h => h(sender, args))
                            .ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit derivitive from @Simon_Weaver answer, but I find it useful. presume you have some class `RaisesEvents` which has an event `RaisesEvents.MyEvent` and you've got it injected to class `MyClass`, where you want to subscribe to `MyEvent` Probably better to do the subscribing in an `Initialize()` method, but for simplicity's sake:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(RaisesEvent otherClass)
    {
        otherClass.MyEvent += MyAction;
    }

    private Action MyAction => async () => await ThingThatReturnsATask();

    public void Dispose() //it doesn't have to be IDisposable, but you should unsub at some point
    {
        otherClass.MyEvent -= MyAction;
    }

    private async Task ThingThatReturnsATask()
    {
        //async-await stuff in here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading/) library mentioned by @ShahinDohan, I wrote a minimal excerpt which ensures that calls to the event delegates are serialized/awaited and that possible exceptions are collected.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncEvents
{
    /// <summary>An asynchronous event handler.
    /// To trigger the event, use the function <see cref="AsyncEventHandlerExtensions.InvokeAsync{TEventArgs}(AsyncEventHandler{TEventArgs}, object, TEventArgs)"/>
    /// instead of <see cref="EventHandler.Invoke(object, EventArgs)"/>, it will guarantee a serialization
    /// of calls to the event delegates and collects any exceptions.
    /// <example><code>
    ///     public event AsyncEventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent;
    /// 
    ///     // Trigger the event
    ///     public async Task OnMyEvent()
    ///     {
    ///         // A null check is not necessary, the ? operator would fail here
    ///         await MyEvent.InvokeIfNotNullAsync(this, new EventArgs());
    ///     }
    /// </code></example>
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEventArgs">The type of event arguments.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="args">Event arguments.</param>
    /// <returns>An awaitable task.</returns>
    public delegate Task AsyncEventHandler<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs args);

    internal static class AsyncEventHandlerExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Invokes asynchronous event handlers, returning an awaitable task. Each handler is fully executed
        /// before the next handler in the list is invoked.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TEventArgs">The type of argument passed to each handler.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="handlers">The event handlers. May be <c>null</c>.</param>
        /// <param name="sender">The event source.</param>
        /// <param name="args">The event argument.</param>
        /// <returns>An awaitable task that completes when all handlers have completed.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="T:System.AggregateException">Thrown if any handlers fail. It contains all
        /// collected exceptions.</exception>
        public static async Task InvokeIfNotNullAsync<TEventArgs>(
            this AsyncEventHandler<TEventArgs> handlers,
            object sender,
            TEventArgs args)
        {
            if (handlers == null)
                return;

            List<Exception> exceptions = null;
            Delegate[] listenerDelegates = handlers.GetInvocationList();
            for (int index = 0; index < listenerDelegates.Length; ++index)
            {
                var listenerDelegate = (AsyncEventHandler<TEventArgs>)listenerDelegates[index];
                try
                {
                    await listenerDelegate(sender, args).ConfigureAwait(true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (exceptions == null)
                        exceptions = new List<Exception>(2);
                    exceptions.Add(ex);
                }
            }

            // Throw collected exceptions, if any
            if (exceptions != null)
                throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
        }
    }
}
```