# Weird behavior with event returning Tasks not fully executing all subscribed methods

Tags: c#, events, async-await, event-handling, task-parallel-library

I have the following event:

```
public static event Func<object, EventArgs, Task> Blocker;
```

I subscribe to it the following anonymous methods:

```
 Blocker += async (x, y) => { await Task.Delay(20); Console.WriteLine("Task1"); };
 Blocker += async (x, y) => { await Task.Delay(10); Console.WriteLine("Task2"); };
 Blocker += async (x, y) => { await Task.Delay(5000); Console.WriteLine("Task3"); };
 Blocker += async (x, y) => { await Task.Delay(1000); Console.WriteLine("Task4"); };
```

Now, if I invoke the event by writing `await Blocker(null,null);`, this returns before all of the subscribed methods have returned, yet if I go down the long path of executing them, by doing the following:

```
foreach (var item in Blocker.GetInvocationList())
{
    await ((Func<object, EventArgs, Task>)item)(null, null);
}
```

No such anomaly is seen.

What exactly is happening here? I thought under the hood, calling the event in turn uses a similar for-loop logic to go through the subscribed methods? I'm guessing it's due to the fact that the await keyword is working on the returned task of `Blocker(null,null)`, and because that's an event, it gets confused and ends up doing the correct behavior, even though for me it looks wrong.

Comment: Only the last `Task` is returned and awaited, because it is a `MulticastDelegate`. I think you need a custom event like you say

Comment: @Charlieface thank you, that cleared it up.

Comment: Check binki's comment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12451628/1672994) answer

Comment: You can also implement what has suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30739162/1672994) answer

Comment: Related: [How do I await events in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761852/how-do-i-await-events-in-c)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I know it's probably considered spam for me writing this, but you've helped me a great deal in the past. Thank you for continuing to do so! Async all the way!