# Async / Await using delegates

Tags: c#, events, async-await

I want to subscribe an async method to an event.

However, the compiler will not let me.

How can I do this?

Example:

```
class SearchBase
{
    public delegate void ReuestingCollectionHandler();
    public event ReuestingCollectionHandler RequestingCollection = null;
}
.
.
.
SearchBase.RequestingCollection += LoadCandidates;


 public async Task LoadCandidates()
 {
    var queryText = string.Empty;
    Candidates = await CandidatesManager.GetCandidates(Profile.Instance.RecruiterId);
 }
```

Comment: Jusr write a wrapper method which will be the delegate function and inside this method call the async method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your `LoadCandidates` method going to be used only as an event handler (like the code you posted shows)?

If so, you should change it to be `async void` instead of returning a `Task`. That's the usual signature for event handlers, and one of the very few cases where having an `async void` method is acceptable/recommended.

If you're gonna use it somewhere else and *need* it to return a task, then write an `async void` wrapper method around it, and use this wrapper as the event handler instead.

```
public async void LoadCandidatesAsync()
 {
    await LoadCandidates();
 }
```

Event handlers should *NOT* return anything. If a caller has 100 clients listening to that event, he will only get the return value of one of the handlers.
If the caller wants to get something out of the handlers, then it should send them a mutable `EventArgs` instance.

Here's a more complete explanation on why event handlers should return `void`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3325425/857807

Comment: Keep in mind that doing this means that when you raise the event, the handlers might be executing in parallel and you won't find out when they complete.

Comment: I've seen quite a few places mention `async void` is valid for event handlers. One specifically mentioned in WPF or Win Forms apps. So just wanted to confirm, is it OK in ASP.NET apps too? e.g. Off a Stopwatch interval callback or say an event raised by a CMS?

Answer (score 1):

Your delegates need to match, you can't assign a method that returns a Task to a delegate of return type void.

Comment: But I cannot apply an "async Task" to a delegate's signature either. So what are my options?

Comment: Async is syntactic sugar to help you build a method that returns a Task. Your delegate should be public delegate Task ReuestingCollectionHandler(). Note that you will are not using events in the standard way, so make sure you're not getting yourself in trouble.

Comment: I like that you are not thinking of changing your LoadCandidates method to async void, which is one of your options. In my humble opinion you should try to use Func<T,...> or Action<T,...> for doing things like this.

Comment: @Zache @fsimonazzi why would an event handler return something other than `void`?

Comment: @dcastro Why would you ever await on a event handler? If you want to await for the handler to complete you need a Task returned from the handler to be awaited on.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The problem with that is that if there are multiple handlers you'll only get one of the tasks, not all of the tasks, unless you have a custom `event` implementation.  awaiting only one of possibly many tasks would be a very bad idea.

Comment: @dcastro I cannot think of a reason for a non-void handler. That's why I addressed the specific question but gave a warning as to the underlying purpose of all this.